# How to create a installer for C# windows application with SQL Server database integrated

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have a C# application that I want to install on my clients computers. It has a SQL Server database connection so that it can store data. I want to create a installer so than I can install the app on clients computer.

So far I tried Installer shield and advanced installer and I could not manage to pull it off.

**NOTE:** I can't install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on clients computer due to toughness.

**NOTE:** I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017 and .NET 4.5 and DevExpress and because I'm using DevExpress I have some reference files to copy to client directory.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you tell in more detail about the kind of data that you store? Specifically, do data from different users have to be stored together?

Comment: No. Each user has its own data stored in his own database.

Comment: Management Studio is not required for running the database. It's only required for managing the server: setting up maintenance tasks, managing server properties, etc. Saying your application needs Management Studio is like telling someone you drive a Sony car, because that's the name you see on the dash. What you probably want is the full **Sql Server Express Edition**.

Comment: Here's the thing: even Express Edition really is a full **SERVER**. That means it wants to act like a server will act: it runs and uses resources _all the time_, even when it's not needed. It will use as much RAM as it can to cache data. Because, again, it's a **server**. As such, using it for a desktop application was probably a _really poor decision_ in the first place. Instead, you would do better with an **in-process** database engine like Sqlite, Firebird, VistaDB, or even MS Access.

Comment: I know and I certainly don't want to install Management Studio on my clients PC, So is there a way I can install my app on client using Express edition?

Comment: Does SQL Compact Edition still exists? Otherwise you can use that.

Comment: Consider using SQLite for this.. You won't need any separate database server, because it is not server based. SQLite simply opens a file on your client's computer, containing a SQLite database. You can combine SQLite with Entity Framework 6, or roll your own System.Data style SQL driven reads and writes, using NuGet package System.Data.SQLite

Comment: SQL Server Express will not gobble up all your memory. It is restricted to using 1GB of memory. The reason you should not deploy it are you don't need to share data. In this case, you should opt for either LocalDB or any of the other in-process databases.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are not sharing their data with one another, **you don't need SQL Server to begin with**. There are other data storage options, ones that don't require an enterprise grade client-server database.

Your app can use a local database such as SQLite. You can use files - JSON or XML allow for easy parsing from C#.